# Browser autofill

Tags: html, autofill

Is there any way I can label or mark my HTML to ensure a field such as "First name" should get autofilled?

Most popular browsers use a regex for field names, e.g. for first name

```
.*name|initials|fname|first$".
```

But changing field names has implications elsewhere; I am limited in what I am permitted to change.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to tell the browser that a field called "abcxyz" should be treated as a "first name" field. There's certainly nothing in the HTML spec for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a form with auto completion on

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I hope that helps it's the best I could find:)

Comment: @Barney if this answer works then share the wealth by choosing best answer please and thank you:) and if it doesn't work then please tell me so i can help.

Comment: You've just posted an example of a form that works. If you read the question again, you'll understand I CAN'T rename my fields to "fname", "email" etc

Comment: The only way I could see you accomplishing this os through lengthy code which is beyond my knowledge. I am sorry I could not help.

Comment: Yeah I hear that, I'd have to rename the fields and rename them back again, bit of a hack. Thanks anyway!